# Swift: ProtocolDelegate optional value error

Tags: ios, swift

I want to delegate some tasks to the AcceptController, but my delegate property inside of 'SendController' always returns nil, so no delegation will ever be executed. I just can't figure out why my delegate property 'übergabeDelegate' always returns nil.

```
protocol ÜbergabeDelegate {
    func übergebeText(text: String)
}

class SendController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

    var übergabeDelegate: ÜbergabeDelegate?

    @IBAction func save(_ sender: UIButton) {
        if let text = textField.text {
            if übergabeDelegate != nil {
                übergabeDelegate!.übergebeText(text: text)
            } else {
                print("\nübergabeDelegate is nil\n")
            }
        }
    }
}

class AcceptController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    let sendController = SendController()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        sendController.übergabeDelegate = self
        //print("Delegate gesetzt")
    }
}

extension AcceptController: ÜbergabeDelegate {
    func übergebeText(text: String) {
        label.text = "\(text)"
    }
}
```

I expect the label to present the input I gave on my SendController but the text of the label never actually changes.

Comment: `SendController()` creates a new instance which is not the instance in the storyboard. You need the actual reference to `SendController` either with a segue or by instantiating/presenting the controller.

Comment: You are right! I think that this is the problem!

Answer (score 1):

inside `viewDidLoad` `let sendController = SendController()` creates a local variable. the `sendController` will then be released after `viewDidLoad` returns. set the `sendController` as a property of the `AcceptController` and the delegate will persist when you assign it because the `SendController` object will not be released after `viewDidLoad` returns.

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You have lifetime issues for `SendController` which would be resolved via the new property `sendController`. Also, it would be proper to declare `SendController.übergabeDelegate ` as a `weak` property because you would be creating a retain cycle.

Comment: But my übergabeDelegate property still returns nil, so the problem still isn't fixed

Comment: @Lukiolio, please post your updated code, so we can see what the changes are, and please show how you are showing your `SendController`

Comment: @Lukiolio, so the `SendController` is getting presented by the `AcceptController`?

Comment: I think I got my error! My let sendController creates a new instance of SendController which is not the reference to my actual SendController in my storyboard!